# Lambda failed silently without any logs, when updating a record from dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using a lambda function for dynamo streaming after a record is inserted.
However, after the dynamoDB.update call, it seems the lambda is dead, and there are no other logs printed. Can anyone help?

Here is my javascript code:

```js
    /* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
      API_SCHOLARGRAPH_EMPLOYEEINFOTABLE_ARN
      API_SCHOLARGRAPH_EMPLOYEEINFOTABLE_NAME
      ENV
      REGION
    Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */


    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    const awsConfig = {
      region: process.env.REGION,
      endpoint:
        process.env.DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT ||
        `https://dynamodb.${process.env.REGION}.amazonaws.com`
    };

    const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(awsConfig);

    async function handleNewEmployeeInfo(dynamoId, employeeId) {
      console.log(
        `[handleNewEmployeeInfo] begin. dynamoId(${dynamoId}) employeeId(${employeeId})`
      );

      try {
        const employeeName = "TestString";

        // this log is working
        console.log(
          'try to update table:',
          process.env.API_SCHOLARGRAPH_EMPLOYEEINFOTABLE_NAME,
          dynamoId,
          employeeName
        );

        // something wrong with the update
        await dynamoDB
          .update({
            TableName: process.env.API_SCHOLARGRAPH_EMPLOYEEINFOTABLE_NAME,
            Key: {
              id: dynamoId
            },
            UpdateExpression: `set employeeName = :employeeName`,
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ':employeeName': employeeName
            }
          })
          .promise()
          .then((data) => console.log(data.Attributes))
          .catch(console.error);
      } catch (error) {
        // NOT working
        console.log('[ERROR]:', error);
      }

      // NOT working
      console.log('[FINISH] call end');
    }

    async function handleEventRecord(record) {
      console.log(record.eventID);
      console.log(record.eventName);

      try {
        // after EmployeeInfo is created by the admin
        if (record.eventName === 'INSERT') {
          const arn = record.eventSourceARN;
          console.log(`[INSERT][${arn}]: ${JSON.stringify(record)}`);
          if (arn.includes(':table/EmployeeInfo')) {
            const dynamoId = record.dynamodb.NewImage.id['S'];
            const employeeId = record.dynamodb.NewImage.employeeId['S'];
            await handleNewEmployeeInfo(dynamoId, employeeId);
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('[ERROR]:', error);
      }
    }

    /**
     * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
     */
    exports.handler = async (event) => {
      console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
      event.Records.forEach(async (record) => {
        await handleEventRecord(record);
      });

      return Promise.resolve('Successfully processed DynamoDB record');
    };
```

After I remove the update logic, the following log works fine. So I am pretty sure it is the update line has the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to update the record and process the update event in the same lambda? It doesn't make much sense, and it doesn't work this way. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Here is the logic: first I create an record EmployeeInfo record from the graphql API Then I want to use Dynamo Stream, to update the employee's attributes. So I am trying to insert an record into DynamoDB, then update the same record by listening the "insert" event. So is this allowed?

Comment: You have two main ways to "listen" to the events in the flow you described, and both are not in DynamoDB. The one is through a GraphQL subscription using a GraphQL client, and the other is in a Lambda that is getting events from DynamoDB Streams.